# Select2 in Table, layout broken

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using simple table and try to add in td select2 but its broken

Need help urgently

html:

```
<td colspan="5" style="padding-left: 5px;">
    <div class="td-justify">
        <span>CUSTOMER:</span>
        <select name="text-customer" class="text-customer customer-id" style="width: 100%; max-width: 341px;">
            @foreach($customers as $customer)
                <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer->company_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

css:

```
       .select2-dropdown {
           z-index:99999;
       }
```

JQuery

`$('.customer-id').select2({tags: true});`

Output
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of html or other text

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add css cdn

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```